# Cookie-based sessions

Tags: web-application, cookies, csrf, session-fixation

During an engagement, i have been asked by a client to explain (with the use of one
or more examples) whether having an authenticated cookie-session web upload
functionality can be dangerous for the security of their system. how can i make explain to them with a use of an example?

Comment: I don't buy the "I have been asked by a client" pretense. This is quite obviously a homework question.

Comment: @MechMK1 lol that's how it's phrased

Comment: If a question is homework, we require that it's labelled as such. There is a huge difference between asking us to helping you with a homework question and asking us to handle customer requests.